# How to get UserHandle of activity in multi user system

Tags: android, android-activity, android-package-managers

I have a service that runs in the background that monitors the foreground activity. At present this does not distinguish between users (multi user accounts Android 4.2). Is there a way that the service can compare the user it is running under with that of the foreground activity? I am only interested in activities of the same user account that the service is running under.

I know I can use:

```
android.os.Process.myUserHandle()
```

to get the UserHandle that the service is running under. But I can't see anything in the docs that can give me the UserHandle of a running activity (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo etc).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Activity always runs as user returned by `android.os.Process.myUserHandle()`.

Answer (score 4):

From inside the service, you can use `android.os.Binder.getCallingUid()` to get the full kernel `uid` of the process containing the Activity that's calling the service. Run this result through `android.os.Process.getUserId()` to get the two digit Android user handle and compare it with `android.os.Process.myUserHandle()`.

Comment: You cannot convert UID to userId using public API. UserHandle.getUserId is not public.